# Detecting when a client has disconnected from my server

Tags: java, sockets, connection

I'm trying to find a way to see when a client that is connected to my server has disconnected. The general structure of my code is like this, I have omitted irrelevant sections of my code:

```
public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
        try {
            ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(port);
            while (true) {
                // wait for connection
                Socket connection = socket.accept();
                // create client socket and start
                Clients c = new Server().new Clients(connection);
                c.start();
                System.out.printf("A client with IP %s has connected.\n",c.ip.substring(1) );
            }
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + exception);
        }
    }

    class Clients extends Thread {
        ...
        public Clients(Socket socket) {         
            clientSocket = socket;
            ip=clientSocket.getRemoteSocketAddress().toString();
            try {
                client_in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                client_out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //error
            }
        }
        public void run() {
            ...
            try {
                while (true) {
                    while ((message = client_in.readLine()) != null) {
                    ...
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException exception) {
                System.out.printf("Client with IP %s has disconnected.\n" , ip.substring(1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Basically what I'm trying at the moment is detecting the disconnection through the catch statement in run(), but the issue with this is it doesn't display the message until I terminate my server.

I have also tried to put my print statement after the while(true) loop but my IDE tells me that code is unreachable.

Is there a way to get my "Client with IP %s has disconnected." to display as soon as the client connection is disconnected? What and where should I be checking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what I'm trying to do is detecting the disconnection through the `catch` statement.

Bzzt. `readLine()` doesn't throw an exception at end of stream. It returns null. Any exception you catch here is an *error*, and should be reported as such.

```
while (true) {
    while ((message = client_in.readLine()) != null) {
        ...
}
```

The problem is here. You *are* detecting when the peer disconnects: `readLine()` returns null and terminates the inner loop. However you have pointlessly enclosed the correct inner read loop in an outer `while (true)` loop, which by definition can never exit.

Remove the outer loop.